# Bash linux script: Putting variables after other over and over

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 variables:

```
GrepMap=$( grep -rl "string" ~/Downloads | cut -d/ -f2 )
GrepDir=$( grep -H -r "string" ~/Downloads )
```

Next I want to show them

```
echo "$GrepMap :  $GrepFile
```

If he found the string in 3 different maps/files
Then my output is like :

```
Portfolio_Macht
Portfolio_Macht
Project_Macht : README.md LES10 index.html
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
Portfolio_Macht : README.md
Portfolio_Macht : LES10
Project_Macht : index.html
```

Anyone can help? Thx!

Comment: can you post the output of individual `grep` commands

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can test it ourselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are `echo`ing one multiline string followed by another, but what you want to do is paste the two multiline scrings together each in its own column. i can think of two ways to fix this. easiest is to use the `paste` command:

```
paste <(echo "$GrepMap") <(echo "$GrepFile")
```

however, why do the same `grep` twice? better would be to `grep` only once, and then use `awk` or `sed` to modify the output:

```
grep -rl "string" ~/Downloads | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)" : "$(NF)}'
```

explanation: use `/` as field separator, then print the second-to-last field`" : "`last field.

Comment: Good suggestion, but if you're going to use `awk` why bother with grep at all? Use awk's pattern matching capabilities to apply the print to only the matched lines and suppress the rest.